# Android DatePicker embed on Activity

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am trying to put a Date Picker embed in the activity as shown in the image bellow: 
[Facebook Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On8Oc.jpg)

I have been searching all over the internet but all the examples that I found, talks about DatePickerDialog. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: [`DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) is a regular `View`. What problems are you having with it?

Comment: Yeah!! You were  right!, android:datePickerMode="spinner" did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this tutorial for date picker and it is working. hope it may help.

http://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-time-picker-dialog

In this tutorial a button and a text view is available to display the date whereas I have a created a button in my activity which displays current date, if the user clicks on that button dater picker dialog will be called and user can enter desired date and the same will appear as button text.